# Options in DropDown using ng-model not getting selected. I need to create ng-model dynamically based on $index and $parent.$index

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

JSON monthA:

```
[
  [
    {
      "monthNumber": "8",
      "monthName": "August"
    },
    {
      "monthNumber": "9",
      "monthName": "Septemeber"
    },
    {
      "monthNumber": "10",
      "monthName": "October"
    },
    {
      "monthNumber": "11",
      "monthName": "November"
    },
    {
      "monthNumber": "12",
      "monthName": "December"
    },
    {
      "monthNumber": "1",
      "monthName": "January"
    },
    {
      "monthNumber": "2",
      "monthName": "February"
    }
  ],
  
]
```

HTML part :

```
<td ng-repeat="ap in monthA" style="width:100px;" align="center" >
    <select ng-model="rishi_Testing" ng-options="value.monthNumber as value.monthName for value in ap track by value.monthNumber">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</td>
```

I am creating a drop down using ng-options with the code written above. But Options are not getting selected. Although I am able to click on options, but they are not getting filled as selected value. Is this because of duplicate ng-models and hence I am trying to create dynamic ng-model?

Comment: you are using a primitve as `ng-model` within `ng-repeat` child scope. Always have a dot in `ng-model`. Read up on scopes and inheritance

Comment: @charlietfl Yes,you mean we need to keep ng-model in binding with JSON we are iterating on. But How to give dynamic values to ng-model??

Comment: can use `$index` or some sort of id from the ng-repeat as key. Declare the rishi_testing object on scope so it gets passed to child scopes

Comment: @charlietfl can you please guide me regarding syntax of using $index in ng-model

Comment: create a demo in plunker or jsfiddle with enough code to create a few of your elements